# Remove specific characters at the end of a string (html elements)

Tags: javascript, php

So I've got a backEnd that returns to me a string by SQL. This string contains this :

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
  ...
  """
</ul>
```

So here's the problem  : you surely have noticed these **" " "**. Before you ask, yes there are unwanted. And I simply want to remove these either by PHP or either par JS. I tried to use substring(), like this :

```
$('.slider ul').html().substr($('.slider ul').html().length - 1)
```

In this code I'm retrieving my list (that was in the string) from my DOM element. Then I tried to remove the last character, but this simply not work.
You can go and check at http://squixdev.byethost16.com/ouvrir-un-fichier-iso-[windows] the output in the console : there 's nothing. You can also notice these **" " "** on the page, at the bottom of the content.

NOTE : I think that I know what adds this strange **" " "** (it's in my backend) but I can't figure how to get rid of it. If you want to check, here's the code that assemble the content and it's at that point that these **" " "** appears :

```
for (i=0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++){
  var id = i + 1
  console.log("getting content of [editor] " + tinymce.editors[i].id)
  console.log("getting content of step_" + pet)
  var content = tinymce.editors[i].getContent();

  console.log( content )

 $('#content li[id="step_' + id + '"] blockquote').append(content);
}
```

I hope someone will find out where is the problem. Best Regards.

Comment: If you know how it gets printed out, why not prevent it from being printed from the first place? That way can save you more hassles, no? :)

Comment: `.substr()` returns a new string, you have to assign it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any of your php, so I can't respond on how to remove them there, but try this:

```
$('.slider ul').html($('.slider ul').html().trim().replace(/" " "$/,''));
```

The trim removes extra space at the end. And the replace is only replacing the 3 quotes at the very end of the string.

Comment: The argument to `.substr()` should be a number.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, copied and pasted part of that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in Javascript you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), but what is your response

var my_string = myString.replace('"""', '');